# PhoneGap + AngularJS how to add camera Plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am new to Phonegap and developing a app for android with phonegap and angularjs. Now i am struck at adding camera plugin.

i am using cordova-plugin-camera.

in Config.xml, when i add

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.2.9" />
```

It shows an error saying: Undefind prefix gap.

my config file placed in appName/res/xml/acofig.xml

how can i add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines you add to config.xml are to add a plugin when you are using the **Phonegap build** online service.

If you are using the command line interface (CLI) to create/build your project, then you should add plugins using the CLI :

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```